# Is it good if during training the model my test accuracy much higher then train accuracy. How can i prevent this?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

my training code:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from torchvision import datasets, transforms


from CNN import CNNmodel

SEED = 5
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
BATCH_SIZE = 16

torch.manual_seed(SEED)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(SEED)

train_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.TrivialAugmentWide(num_magnitude_bins=8),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

test_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

train_data = datasets.MNIST(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=train_transform
)

test_data = datasets.MNIST(
    root="data",
    train=False,
    download=True,
    transform=test_transform
)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(
    train_data,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=True
)

test_dataloader = DataLoader(
    test_data,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=False
)

channel_num = train_data[0][0].shape[0]
model = CNNmodel(in_shape=channel_num, hidden_shape=16, out_shape=len(train_data.classes)).to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params=model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
epochs = 20
writer = SummaryWriter(log_dir="runs\\CNN_MNIST")

for epoch in range(epochs):
    train_loss = 0
    train_acc = 0

    model.train()
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
        X = torch.reshape(X, (BATCH_SIZE, channel_num, 28, 28))

        y_pred = model(X)

        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
        train_loss += loss.item()
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

        y_pred_class = torch.argmax(torch.softmax(y_pred, dim=1), dim=1)
        train_acc += (y_pred_class == y).sum().item()/len(y_pred)
    
    train_loss /= len(train_dataloader)
    train_acc /= len(train_dataloader)
    
    test_loss = 0
    test_acc = 0

    model.eval()
    with torch.inference_mode():
        for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(test_dataloader):
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

            y_pred = model(X)

            loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
            test_loss += loss.item()

            y_pred_class = torch.argmax(torch.softmax(y_pred, dim=1), dim=1)
            test_acc += (y_pred_class == y).sum().item()/len(y_pred)
    
    test_loss /= len(test_dataloader)
    test_acc /= len(test_dataloader)

   
    writer.add_scalars(
        main_tag="Loss",
        tag_scalar_dict={"train_loss": train_loss,
                        "test_loss": test_loss   },
        global_step=epoch
    )

    writer.add_scalars(
        main_tag="Accuracy", 
        tag_scalar_dict={"train_acc": train_acc,
                        "test_acc": test_acc   }, 
        global_step=epoch
    )

    writer.close()
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    print(f"epoch={epoch}, train loss={train_loss}, train acc={train_acc}, test loss={test_loss}, test acc={test_acc}\n")

torch.save(model.state_dict(), f="CNN.pth")
```

my results:

epoch=0, train loss=1.2992823556999364, train acc=0.5814166666666667, test loss=0.1535775218948722, test acc=0.9617

epoch=1, train loss=0.7351227536817392, train acc=0.7735333333333333, test loss=0.0957084314838983, test acc=0.9711

epoch=2, train loss=0.6108905077829957, train acc=0.8069666666666667, test loss=0.10527049974631518, test acc=0.968

epoch=3, train loss=0.5531635082634787, train acc=0.8209333333333333, test loss=0.09478655792670325, test acc=0.9719

epoch=4, train loss=0.5146081379964947, train acc=0.8315666666666667, test loss=0.10086005784235895, test acc=0.9717

epoch=5, train loss=0.48089857985948525, train acc=0.8415166666666667, test loss=0.07805026951334439, test acc=0.9755

epoch=6, train loss=0.46410337663746126, train acc=0.8458, test loss=0.06370123700092081, test acc=0.979

epoch=7, train loss=0.45169676643597584, train acc=0.8508333333333333, test loss=0.06549387282291427, test acc=0.9784

epoch=8, train loss=0.4308121643635134, train acc=0.8575, test loss=0.07395816469893325, test acc=0.9764

epoch=9, train loss=0.42585810295939447, train acc=0.8576166666666667, test loss=0.060803520213114096, test acc=0.9809

epoch=10, train loss=0.412179026115189, train acc=0.8625, test loss=0.05902050706697628, test acc=0.9811

epoch=11, train loss=0.4062708326317991, train acc=0.8628666666666667, test loss=0.05916510981819592, test acc=0.982

epoch=12, train loss=0.3950844133876264, train acc=0.8676666666666667, test loss=0.051657470285263844, test acc=0.9839

epoch=13, train loss=0.3960405339717865, train acc=0.8668666666666667, test loss=0.05090424774668645, test acc=0.9838

epoch=14, train loss=0.3826637831449664, train acc=0.8697333333333334, test loss=0.049632979356194845, test acc=0.9839

epoch=15, train loss=0.38186972920044016, train acc=0.87205, test loss=0.05163152083947789, test acc=0.9828

epoch=16, train loss=0.37976737998841953, train acc=0.8736166666666667, test loss=0.054158556177618444, test acc=0.9823

epoch=17, train loss=0.3711047379902874, train acc=0.8751333333333333, test loss=0.055461415114835835, test acc=0.9816

epoch=18, train loss=0.369529847216544, train acc=0.87475, test loss=0.046305917761620366, test acc=0.9861

epoch=19, train loss=0.3628049560392275, train acc=0.8773833333333333, test loss=0.05091290192245506, test acc=0.9846

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a large gap suggests a problem with your test data. Maybe there is a data leak (i.e. part of your test data is leaked directly or indirectly into the training data).

Comment: yeah, you are right, i've downloaded my train and test data in one folder, thanks